# Mapping sibling nodes using xPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I need a way to parse an XML file and link certain nodes with their siblings. For example, in this XML (not my actual data, just a sample) I am trying to link all of the RecordDetail nodes with the preceding RecordHeader.

XML:

```
<RecordSet>
    <RecordHeader>
        <Record_ID>HE7</Record_ID>
        <DetailRecords>2</DetailRecords>
    </RecordHeader>
    <RecordDetail>
        <Product_ID>1-1X00</Product_ID>
        <Quantity>5</Quantity>
    </RecordDetail>
    <RecordDetail>
        <Product_ID>1-3788</Product_ID>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    </RecordDetail>
</RecordSet>
```

Expected Output:

```
Product_ID   Record_ID
----------------------
1-1X00       HE7
1-3788       HE7
```

I can get the sibling node with the following expression, but it is only listed once:

```
//RecordDetail/preceding-sibling::RecordHeader/Record_ID/node()
```

Is there a way to list out *every* RecordDetail node, accompanied by the RecordHeader node that precedes it?

There will always be a record header, followed by any number of RecordDetail nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the output without the header with the following XPath-2.0 expression:

```
for $i in //RecordDetail return concat($i/Product_ID/text(),'&#09;&#09;',$i/preceding-sibling::RecordHeader[1]/Record_ID,'&#xa;')
```

Its output is

```
1-1X00         HE7
1-3788         HE7
```

Answer (score 0):

With XPath 1.0, you could use the below xpath:

`//RecordHeader/following-sibling::RecordDetail/concat(concat(Product_ID/text(), '    '), preceding-sibling::RecordHeader/Record_ID/text())`

What it does is it gets all sibling of `RecordHeader` gets their `Product_ID` appends it with its preceding sibling `RecordHeader`'s `Record_ID`.